# Reveal Modal Popup doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="salt">
        <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fadeAndPop">
            <img src="img/CLR.jpg" width="116px" height="48px">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>content could go in here.</p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

on click that image nothing will display.

reavel.js link is
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48992367/AppzVenture/extra/jquery.reveal.js

jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/8Leu4/2/

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: Here is jsfiddle...   http://jsfiddle.net/8Leu4/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what's missing in your code : 
the link of the reveal CSS file ;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reveal.css">
```

include the jquery 1.4.4 or higher 
and include jquery reveal 
the files needed for this can be downloaded from [here](http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/122/reveal.zip)
so your code should be like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reveal.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.reveal.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="salt">
        <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fadeAndPop">
            <img src="img/CLR.jpg" width="116px" height="48px"/>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <h1>Modal Title</h1>
        <p>Any content could go in here.</p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```